# Estimator preferred over the other

Tags: st.statistics, counterexamples

Suppose $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ two estimators of the mean $\mu$ knowing that $MSE(\theta_2) = MSE(\theta_1)$, $\theta_1$ estimates $\mu$ with a bias and $\theta_2$ estimates $\mu$ without a bias. We know in this situation that $\theta_2$ is preferred over $\theta_1$ to estimate $\mu$. Can you give a single concrete example where it is the case and why in that example you think $\theta_2$ is preferred over $\theta_1$?

Comment: This is not research-level math; further, it looks like homework. As such, it does not belong on mathoverflow, which is for research-level problems.

Comment: @user44191 This is research-level. In the literature, it says when $MSE(\theta_1) = MSE(\theta_2)$, then we can't conclude which estimator is preferred. I try to find an example to disprove that.

Comment: Glossary: MSE = Mean squared error

Comment: In your original post, you did not say that $\mu$ was the mean. You should not change your question to invalidate a valid answer. Anyhow, now you have a "mean" counterexample as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\si\sigma$Here is an example of two estimators, one biased and one unbiased, with the same MSE:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be an iid sample from $N(0,\si^2)$, with $n\ge3$ and unknown $\si^2$, to be estimated. Let
$$T_1:=S^2:=\frac1{n-1}\,\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X_n)^2,$$
the sample variance, where $\bar X_n:=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, the sample mean of the sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

Let
$$T_2:=\frac1{n-1}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(X_i-\bar X_{n-2})^2;$$
here, of course, $\bar X_{n-2}=\frac1{n-2}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} X_i$.

Then the estimators $T_1$ and $T_2$ of $\si^2$ are, respectively, unbiased and biased, with the same MSE, equal $2\si^4/(n-1)$ (see e.g. the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Gaussian_distribution)).

---

As for preferring, of two estimators with the same MSE, the unbiased one -- in general there is no reason whatsoever for that, **assuming that the true costs are given by the quadratic function**. On the other hand, in reality the true costs are hardly ever given by the quadratic function, and this cost/loss function is usually used just because of its utter analytic simplicity. But if the true costs are far from quadratic, then the very use of the MSE makes no sense, as well as all this bias-versus-variance matter.

---

**Responding to comments by the OP:**

**"You took the variance $\si^2$ while the question is referring to the mean $\mu$. Can you add another example taking that into account?"**

In your original post, you did not say that $\mu$ was the mean. Anyhow, here is the "mean" example for you:

$\newcommand\th\theta$Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be an iid sample from $U(0,\th)$, the uniform distribution on the interval $(0,\th)$, for real real $\th>0$. The mean of this distribution is $\mu=\th/2$. Let
$$S_1:=a_n X_{n:n},\quad S_2:=b_n X_{n:n},$$
where $X_{n:n}:=\max_i X_i$, the largest [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution),
$$a_n:=\frac{n+1}{2n},\quad b_n:=\frac{n^2+2n-1}{2n(n+1)}.$$
Then the estimators $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $\mu$ are, respectively, unbiased and biased, with the same MSE, equal $\th^2/(4n(n+2))$.

**"Can you explain rigorously why you think $T1$ is a better estimator over  $T2$"**

I did not say that I think $T_1$ is better than $T_2$. To the contrary, I said "As for preferring, of two estimators with the same MSE, the unbiased one -- in general there is no reason whatsoever for that, **assuming that the true costs are given by the quadratic function**."

As for "rigorous", if you want something rigorous, then you have to have rigorous definitions in place. In this case, it would be **your job** to tell us by what rigorous criterion, in addition to that of the MSE, you want to compare estimators. If that criterion is a smaller bias, then you will have your desired result immediately and automatically.

Comment: For you, what could be a rigorous definition to tell $T_1$ is a better estimator over $T_2$? When you showed the example with estimators on $\sigma^2$, it seems you played with the size of the sample.

Comment: @Alex : As I said, you could just say right away that you prefer unbiased estimators, given two estimators with the same MSE -- which would the beginning and end of the discussion. But, as I also said, to offer whatever additional criterion you want to use would be your job, not anyone else's.

Comment: In the literature, it says independently if two estimators, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, are biased or not, if $MSE(\theta_1) = MSE(\theta_2)$, then we cannot conclude which estimator is preferred. It blows my mind how far this definition is not rigorous. I would therefore like to find a criterion associated with a counterexample to demonstrate that this definition does not hold water. I have just no idea what might be this criterion.

Comment: With the first instance you came up with, I had the impression there was a hidden criterion, but I am not sure how to formulate it mathematically.

Comment: @Alex : The assertion "if two estimator have the same MSE, then we cannot conclude which estimator is preferred" is not mathematical, because the term "preferred" is undefined and non-mathematical. Also, this assertion is an assertion, not a definition of any sort. Also, I see nothing hidden here. As I said, "you could just say right away that you prefer unbiased estimators, given two estimators with the same MSE -- which would the beginning and end of the discussion." I can see nothing else here.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Also, you cannot mathematically "demonstrate that this definition does not hold water" without defining mathematically the meaning of "holding water".

Comment: What did you use to give me the two examples? You just said yourself "Humm, I am going to spit two estimators such that they have the same MSE, and one is biased and not the other".

Comment: @Alex : Concerning the first example, I basically used the Wikipedia table referred to in the answer. For the second example, I noticed that the MSE of $aX_{n:n}$ is a quadratic function of $a$, so that the equation $MSE(aX_{n:n})=MSE(a_nX_{n:n})$ may have two distinct real roots $a$, which turned out to be the case here, with roots $a=a_n$ and $a=b_n$.

Comment: Ok, in each of these instances, I assume you prefer the unbiased estimator over the bias. (Otherwise, you wouldn't have given me these two very specific examples). According to my question and your **opinion**, why in these examples you think $θ_2$ is **preferred** over $θ_1$? You must have at least a good reason why you have chosen theses instances.

Comment: I already explained how I chose those estimators, and I already said, more than once, that I do **not** see good reasons to prefer one of the estimators in each pair to the other. I have no hidden preferences. I gave these examples just because you requested them: two estimators, biased and unbiased, with the same MSE.

Comment: The question is "Can you give a single concrete example where it is the case and why in that example you think $θ_2$ is preferred over $θ_1$?" You did not respect that according to what you've just said : "I do not see good reasons to prefer one of the estimators in each pair to the other." So your answer is just useless.

Comment: The problem was really that your very question is loaded with a wrong preconception. As I have been trying to tell you, indeed, as you saw in the literature, there are no good reasons to prefer one of two estimators with the same MSE to the other, unless **you** have your own personal reasons.